# Microsoft App authentication in MVC 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to authenticate my mvc application by microsoft. I successfully done with Facbook, Google and Twitter, but when i click on Microsoft then the error `We're unable to complete your request

Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later`
is coming.

I successfully created an app and paste the Client ID and Client Secret in my mvc application . But I do not know the real problem

Comment: While creating my app in Microsoft, I didn't provide the privacy and service URL . Are these mandatory?

Answer (score 3):

What is the return URL that you specified for the given Client ID and Client Secret?  If the site is not running under that specific URL (e.g. is running under localhost whilst you are in dev mode), you can get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had my gmail account configured as my primary Microsoft Live account once I changed this to my Hotmail account as the primary account and then created a new app with a new name Client ID and Secret it started working for me.

The gmail account worked signing in as a gmail user on my app Identity Provider being Google to give some background this is the account I used as my Microsoft Account. I suspect my Microsoft account using my gmail user name and password confused the MS identity Provider thus resulting in the error. So avoid using a different Identity Providers credentials to authenticate with a different Identity provider if testing this.  One account per Identity provider not associated to other Identity providers.

Since the Google account had been my primary for the other Identity Providers when I logged into the App as this I as essentially I suspect therefore already logged in with my Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:-

Open Application Registration Portal of Microsoft [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com] where you have Registered your Application.

**You need to make change in Redirect URIs**

**For example :-**

The URI which is Registered

URL:- http://localhost:8000

[image: Setting Redirect URI]

**Change to make in URI :-**

Just Add :- [/signin-microsoft] at end of URL It works

URL:- http://localhost:8000/signin-microsoft

[image]

Finally save your setting and try again it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it failed when I used my personal Outlook account to login.

Once I switched to an Office 365 account, it started working.